# Retrofit cant get header token

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Im trying to get my token to logout from the apps and send the token to header to logout
and the code is like this

> in Fragment

```
val bundle = this.arguments
    if (bundle != null) {
        myInt = bundle!!.getString(token)
        println("initoken : Bearer $myInt")
    }else
        logout.setOnClickListener{
            var response = RetroFitClient().apiService.logout(myInt)
            response.enqueue( object : Callback<logoutResponse>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<logoutResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<logoutResponse>, response: Response<logoutResponse>) {
                    var logoutres = response.isSuccessful
                    if(logoutres != null){
                        sharedPrefManager?.saveSPBoolean(SharedPrefManager().SP_SUDAH_LOGIN, false)
                        startActivity(
                            Intent(activity, loginActivity::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        )
                        activity?.onBackPressed()
                        Toast.makeText(activity, response.body()?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }else Toast.makeText(activity,"cant login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            })

        }
```

> In Interface Api.kt

```
interface Api {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("auth/login")
fun login(
    @Field("username") username: String?,
    @Field("password") password: String?
): Call<loginResponse>

@POST("auth/logout")
fun logout(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String?
) : Call<logoutResponse>
```

}

> And this is my retrofitclient

```
class RetroFitClient {
var Base_URL = "http://devi.darkotech.id:49001/api/v1/"
var token : String = "";

fun Token(token: String ) {
    this.token = token;
}

var okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(
        object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                var request = chain.request()

                if(request.header("No-Authentication")==null){
                    //val token = getTokenFromSharedPreference();
                    //or use Token Function
                    if(!token.isNullOrEmpty())
                    {
                        val finalToken =  "Bearer "+token
                        request = request.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization",finalToken)
                            .build()
                    }

                }

                return chain.proceed(request)
            }
        }
    ).build()
//RetroFit Builder
val retrofitBuilder : Retrofit.Builder by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Base_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
}
//Class API Service pada slide sebelumnya
val apiService : Api by lazy {
    retrofitBuilder
        .build()
        .create(Api::class.java)
}
```

}

> and this is my postman

if i login i got the token[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Cx3.png)

and after i got the token i use it for logout 
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9wJC.png)

i can get the login token and now i dont know how to work with the header using the bearer token to logout
Thanks

Comment: can you remove `.client(okHttpClient)` and try ? as you are passing `myInt` in `@Header`. Just pass `"Bearer myInt"` to logout API call after removing client.

Comment: How did you fix?

Comment: im just add Bearer on my token